# How are IPL players paid?

Tags: cricket, finances, indian-premier-league

In the Indian Premier League, the players are auctioned to the different teams and their salaries depends on the auction amount. But who pays them, does the IPL administration pay them or do the team owners pay them?

If they are paid by the team owners, can the owners decide to increase or decrease their salaries later?

Comment: I want to know if bid goes to any one 5 crore then it's only for one year or 3 years .....

Answer (score 13):

Each player has to sign a contract with BCCI.

The IPL has two type of contracts – under **first**, called the firm agreement, the player will get a fixed sum from BCCI and the difference between the bid amount and the fixed fee will be earned by BCCI,

On the other hand the **second**, called the basic agreement, gives a player freedom to take home the amount he has been bid for. The average amount of money each player will take home is whopping Rs 80 lakhs.

IPL also makes it mandatory for a franchise to spend at least $3.3 million annually for player fees and give $100 as per day per player daily allowance.

International players will be immediately released to attend their international matches if they clash with IPL whereas for domestic boards, which rely heavily on the players, will have to give way to IPL as players need to decide where they want to play, and a player who gets Rs 80 lakhs for 45 days will not leave IPL anyhow.

Hence, it will be a loss to domestic boards but a great opportunity for youngsters who don’t get chance to perform in national and international leagues.

Comment: Nice one, can you tell which contracts usually happen - first or second ? if it is first, than if gambhir sold for 10 crores , bcci will get 10 crores and bcci will give salary for gambhir ?